# Display content one after another with various intervals

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have two arrays in my javascript:

```
var content = ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"],
    milliseconds = [500, 1500, 1000, 500];
```

I want each element of `content` array to be displayed in console one by one with intervals from `milliseconds` array in a way that `string1` is displayed after 500 milliseconds, `string2` after 1500 (from the displaying of `string1`) and so on.

I'm a total beginner, I tried stuff like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < content.length - 1; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(content[i]);
    }, milliseconds[i]);
};
```

But it displays only the last string four times, and it looks like `setTimeout` methods all start at the same time, not one after another. Is there a way to get the effect I want?

Comment: It's worth noting that you're delving into a programming concept called "closures".  It appears in the form of the function you feed to the `setTimeout` function.  Your closure refers to the `i` variable, but the for-loop is updating `i` on every iteration.  Thus, by the time setTimeout runs each function, `i` is 4 because the for-loop stopped at `i = 4`.

Comment: Also, don't do `i < content.length - 1`. Think about it: `i` starts at 0, and `content.length` is going to be 4 in this case. At what point is `i` _less than_ (4-1)? It's `2` - but the index that you want isn't 2, it's 3. Either use `i < content.length` or `i <= content.length - 1` - preferably the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the `setTimeout`s all seem to start at the same time because you're calling them at the same time. JavaScript doesn't block - it doesn't wait for the `setTimeout` callback to actually fire, it just keeps going. That's why, since you were using a loop, all of the callbacks were getting scheduled more or less at once.

The second issue, that all of the `console.log`s seem to print the same thing, is because of the same loop issue. Since the loop finishes way before any of the callbacks complete, the value of `i` is set to the last index of the loop. Then, when the callback occurs, guess what `i` is equal to?

One technique would be to just keep a running index of the current item.

```
// Don't pollute the global namespace
(function() {
    // Keep the index around
    var i = 0;

    // Setup the callback
    var callback = function() {
        console.log(content[i]);

        // Stop whenever there's nothing left to log
        if (i < content.length) {
            // Chain the next timeout, using the next string,
            // with the next wait period, using the callback
            i += 1;
            setTimeout(callback, milliseconds[i]);
        }
    };

    // Start the first setTimeout
    setTimeout(callback, milliseconds[i]);
})();
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot, now it seems so obvious :) So basically it calls the `callback` function once with a delay of `milliseconds[0]` and then inside that function it displays first string, updates the index and iterates until there's nothing left. And that's a recursive call, right?

Comment: @user1492091: Yes, basically. It's more of a "recursive setTimeout", because it's not being called directly. :]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the fourth string being logged each time, unfortunately my phone doesn't allow me to run it, but I can see exactly why all 4 timeouts start at the same time. It's because they are all created at the same time. If you want them to start one after the other, you'll have to make each one start the next ones timeout.